# python web server потоки?

Tags: python

я написал скрипт на python по обработке фото он довольно долго работает 15-30 секунд. Я хочу повесить этот скрипт на веб сервер что бы сервер принимал фото post запросом с параметрами обрабатывал его и выдавал грубо говоря уже ссылку на обработанное фото в json, пробовал несколько разных веб серверов везде сталкиваюсь с одной проблемой запросы выполняются в 1 поток по очередии, грубо говоря ждет пока завершится обработка 1 запроса, а мне надо что бы при каждом post запросе веб сервер как бы создавал отдельный поток, например если 2 запроса одновременно то они должны выполнится в +/- одно время, а не по очереди. ВОт пример на bottle, но по сути все фреймворки веб сервера +/- одинаковые, везде один результат мб это из за того что я с одного локального пк делаю запросы, такое чувство что я упираюсь в какую то сессию даже если открыть 2 вкладки в браузере и одновременно обратиться к веб серверу запросы не выполнятся паралельно? Единственный вариант который я вижу это запускать N веб серверов на разных портах и делать какой то балансировщик? Какие еще есть варианты?

```
@route('/api/wmgen', method='POST')
def apiwmgen():
time.sleep(30)
return data
run(host='localhost', port=8000, debug=True, server='paste')
```

Comment: на пайтоне можно организовать асинхронку хошешь многопоточность или мнопросецорность

Comment: Простые веб сервисы питона все однопоточные, нужно что-то посерьёзнее брать. Названия не назову, просто имейте в виду, это действительно так. Ну то есть и на питоне есть более серьёзные решения, но это не flask, bottle и т.д.

Comment: Долгие задачи вообще должен делать не веб-сервер, а какой-нибудь фоновый процесс

Comment: @andreymal Я тоже к этому пришел, вызываю python скрипт прям из очереди laravel             $python =  shell_exec('c:\Users\info\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe d:\tmp_work\py\ratly\php_exec\main.py '.$json_result);
Прям очень хорошо работает)

Answer (score 0):

нужно использовать многопоточный сервер

```py
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, ThreadingHTTPServer

httpd = ThreadingHTTPServer(('',8078),Handler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```